# Notepad++ NppExec: Execute / Pass multiple files to compiler

Tags: notepad++, nppexec

currently im using this script to pass a file to the VALA Compiler:

```
cd $(CURRENT_DIRECTORY)
valac $(FILE_NAME)
```

The problem is very obvious.
With this command, i'm just passing one file to the compiler.
The command has to be like that:

```
valac file1.vala file2.vala fileN.vala
```

The problem is, i don't know how to say that to NppExec. There's no Environment Variable, that equals all files in the directory or sth. like that.
The script only had to get all *.vala files in the directory and pass them in the appropiate syntax to the compiler.

Has anyone an idea, how to realize that ?

Greetz!

Answer (score 0):

You could always make use of the INPUTBOX feature:

```
INPUTBOX "Enter list of vala files to include, separated by spaces"

valac $(INPUT[1]) $(INPUT[2]) $(INPUT[3]) $(INPUT[4])
```